# why do i get a weird output when i select substraction from the available choices

Tags: c++

I do get this message/output after the the message says difference can not be negative. i uploaded a photo of the output

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

//Prototype
double add(double, double);
double subtract(double, double);
double multiply(double, double);
double divide(double, double);
void Choices();

int main()
{
    /// your program should work with doubles at all cases
    /// add more comments on the code. polish your code 

    // variable declaration:
    // To be used in the loop
    double x, y;
    int choice = 0;

    // loop execution
    for (int i = 0; choice != 5; i++)
    {
        Choices();
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            cout << "Enter first number: ";
            cin >> x;
            cout << "Enter second number: ";
            cin >> y;
            cout << "Sum " << add(x, y) << endl;
            cout << "---------------------------" << endl << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            cout << "Enter first number: ";
            cin >> x;
            cout << "Enter second number: ";
            cin >> y;
            cout << "Difference: " << subtract(x, y) << endl;
            cout << "---------------------------" << endl << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            cout << "Enter first number: ";
            cin >> x;
            cout << "Enter second number: ";
            cin >> y;
            cout << "Product: " << multiply(x, y) << endl;
            cout << "---------------------------" << endl << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 4)
        {
            cout << "Enter first number: ";
            cin >> x;
            cout << "Enter second number: ";
            cin >> y;
            cout << "Division: " << divide(x, y) << endl;
            cout << "---------------------------" << endl << endl;
        }

        else if (choice == 5)
        {
            /// number 5 is not an invald number
            cout << "Exit" << endl;
            cout << "You tried " << i << " times before you hit the end" << endl;
            cout << "---------------------------" << endl << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        else if (choice >= 6 || choice <= 0)
        {
            /// the program should not close after entering an invalide number
            cout << choice << " is not an option" << endl;
            cout << "------------------------------";
            cout << endl << endl;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
// To provide the avaialable choices/optioins:
void Choices()
{
    cout << "A menu driven program" << endl;
    cout << "1: Addition of two Numbers" << endl;
    cout << "2: Subtraction of two Numbers" << endl;
    cout << "3: Multiplicaion of two Numbers" << endl;
    cout << "4: Division of two Numbers " << endl;;
    cout << "5: Exit " << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your choice: ";
}

// To add two numbers
double add(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}

//To substract two numbers
double subtract(double a, double b)
{
    int difference = 0;
    difference = a - b;
    if (difference < 0)
    {
        cout << "The difference can not be negative";
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
    else if (difference > 0)
    {
        return difference;
    } /// the diffrence can't be negative. it is always posative. diffrence between 5 and 3 is 2. diffrence between 3 and 5 is 2.
}

// To multiply two numbers
double multiply(double a, double b)
{
    return a * b;
}

// To divide two numbers
double divide(double a, double b)
{
    return a / b;
}
```

I just want to know why the message is popping.I did not get this message before using the if statement not allowing the negative number to be not outputted but after using that statement i do receive this output or the message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxYsh.png)

Comment: From your comments - ("diffrence between 5 and 3 is 2. diffrence between 3 and 5 is 2") - it looks like you're supposed display the absolute value of the difference, not an error message.

Comment: @molbdnilo i was confused about that when i sent the code and i got i back the /// are feedbacks but i ask my freind and he meant that it was supposed to not return anything or just a message saying it can not be.Can i know why i have three down votes was my question bad or my description about it.I am trying to ask some good questions but i get a down vote everytime lol.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of your code is undefined. Your `subtract` function does not return an explicit value on all control paths (including the "negative" branch).

Using that return value is where the undefined behaviour creeps in.

One solution would be to throw an exception instead (`throw "The difference can not be negative";`), and catch that in the caller with a `catch (const char* e)`.

(Also your casting the result of the subtraction to an `int` is suspect too - as a rule of thumb, don't mix up your data types.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggested you used `return NULL`
`substract` should return something because you specify its data type to be a `double`. Only `void` functions don't need to return something.
 if you didn't specify  the return value, the compiler just return `not a number(nan)` as default

```
//To substract two numbers
double subtract(double a, double b)
{
    int difference = 0;
    difference = a - b;
    if (difference < 0)
    {
        cout << "The difference can not be negative";
        cout << endl << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (difference > 0)
    {
        return difference;
    } /// the diffrence can't be negative. it is always posative. diffrence between 5 and 3 is 2. diffrence between 3 and 5 is 2.
    else return NULL;
}
```

Comment: thanks but i still did not learn null you and bathsheba clarify my doubt i fix and update it

Comment: I thought NULL was for pointers.  How about returning `0.0` instead?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ```NULL```is a ```placeholder``` for a data value that is not known or not specified, ```0.0```  technically is a numerical value .Please check the link  https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-actual-difference-between-NULL-and-0-zero?fbclid=IwAR2gF9cij42qbYYs1Xbpscgc5lXmKJdelreA597oSrrK0OgG9ZmqvACz7d4

Answer (score 0):

Now it is working

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

//Prototype
double add(double, double);
void subtract(double, double);
double multiply(double, double);
double divide(double, double);
void Choices();

int main()
{
    /// your program should work with doubles at all cases
    /// add more comments on the code. polish your code 

    // variable declaration:
    double x, y;
    int choice = 0;

    // loop execution
    for (int i = 0; choice != 5; i++)
    {
        Choices();
        cin >> choice;

        //To perform a certain operation each time a choice is selected
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            cout << "Enter first number: ";
            cin >> x;
            cout << "Enter second number: ";
            cin >> y;
            cout << "Sum " << add(x, y) << endl;
            cout << "---------------------------" << endl << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            cout << "Enter first number: ";
            cin >> x;
            cout << "Enter second number: ";
            cin >> y;
            subtract(x, y);
            cout << "---------------------------" << endl << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            cout << "Enter first number: ";
            cin >> x;
            cout << "Enter second number: ";
            cin >> y;
            cout << "Product: " << multiply(x, y) << endl;
            cout << "---------------------------" << endl << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 4)
        {
            cout << "Enter first number: ";
            cin >> x;
            cout << "Enter second number: ";
            cin >> y;
            cout << "Division: " << divide(x, y) << endl;
            cout << "---------------------------" << endl << endl;
        }

        //To end the program once exit choice is selected
        else if (choice == 5)
        {
            /// number 5 is not an invald number
            cout << "Exit" << endl;
            cout << "You tried " << i << " times before you hit the end" << endl;
            cout << "---------------------------" << endl << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        else if (choice >= 6 || choice <= 0)
        {
            /// the program should not close after entering an invalide number
            cout << choice << " is not an option" << endl;
            cout << "------------------------------";
            cout << endl << endl;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

// To provide the avaialable choices/optioins:
void Choices()
{
    cout << "A menu driven program" << endl;
    cout << "1: Addition of two Numbers" << endl;
    cout << "2: Subtraction of two Numbers" << endl;
    cout << "3: Multiplicaion of two Numbers" << endl;
    cout << "4: Division of two Numbers " << endl;;
    cout << "5: Exit " << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your choice: ";
}

// To add two numbers
double add(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}

//To substract two numbers
void subtract(double a, double b)
{
    //variable declaration to store the difference
    int difference = 0;

    //The equation
    difference = a - b;

    //To assure the difference is not negative 
    if (difference < 0)
    {
        cout << "The difference can not be negative";
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
    else if (difference >= 0)
    {
        cout << "The difference is: ";
        cout << difference;
        cout << endl << endl;
        return;
    } /// the diffrence can't be negative. it is always posative. diffrence between 5 and 3 is 2. diffrence between 3 and 5 is 2.
}

// To multiply two numbers
double multiply(double a, double b)
{
    return a * b;
}

// To divide two numbers
double divide(double a, double b)
{
    return a / b;
}
```

Comment: Also an array of function pointers, given that the functions all have the same parameters and return type.